# Extra options missing from Run/Debug Configurations menu

Tags: android, android-studio

From the screenshot below you can see that there are a few options missing in Android studio for me.

Does anyone have any ideas why they are missing or how I can access them?

```
Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
Mac OS X 10.12.6
```

### My Android Studio

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

### Extra options mentioned in docs

[image: Related Android Studio docs]

### Screenshot with Extra options available

This is a random one I found online

[image: Android Studio with options screenshot]